# Take a guess or make a guess

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

What's the difference between "take a guess" and "make a guess"? Seems like they're both grammatically correct.

For example:

> I don't know how old she is, I can only make/take a guess.

Comment: I mostly hear "take a guess" being used imperatively, while I would say "make a guess" if I'm the one doing it. (But corpus results suggest that both are used interchangeably.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker, I just want to confirm you are correct.  While in my region of the U.S., I hear "take" much more often -- and I don't even know if other regions are different -- I don't think either is any more correct ... perhaps merely a preference.  They are not only grammatically/technically correct, but they are also both in broad common use.

So I would call these 100% interchangeable.